# Controller do Angular não renderiza na minha Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Não consigo fazer renderizar um script na minha página _Layout. Coloquei na _Layout, junto das declarações dos Bundles e no debug do Chrome, na Aba Network vem com status 304. Coloquei na parte superior da página(_Layout) e também não funcionou. Removi os "~" e também nada. Retirei da _Layout e pus na Index, tanto na parte superior quanto na inferior e nada também. Veja uma imagem do debug do chrome como está. O controller do Angular(Ele não funciona) e também coloquei um bootstrap.css e deu a mesma coisa(304).
Esse é o erro:

> TipoContatoOperadoraController.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   TipoContatoOperadoraController is not defined

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu Controller.js(AngularJS)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController]);

function tipoContatoOperadora($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:7215/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora').success(function (data) {

        $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;

    }).error(function () {

        $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';

    });
}
```

Essa é minha _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Tipo Contato Operadora", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Lista de Tipo Contato Operadora", "Index", "GetTipoContatoOperadora", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/TipoContatoOperadoraController.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

O que está errado nessa abordagem? O que eu quero é consumir um WebAPI usando AngularJS, nada mais.

Aqui está o código da minha Index. Será que essa linha pode estar fazendo a diferença?

```
<div data-ng-controller="TipoContatoOperadoraController">
```

Aí está.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Tipo Contato Operadora</h2>

<div data-ng-controller="TipoContatoOperadoraController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Lista de Tipo de Contato das Operadoras</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>{{erro}}</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Cod. Tipo Contato</th>
                                <th>Nome Tipo Contato</th>
                                <th>Ind. Tipo Contato</th>
                                <th>Data Atualização</th>
                                <th>Cod. Usuário</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="lista in listaTipoContatoOperadora">
                                <td>{{ lista.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.tipoContato }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.dataUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.loginUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No `<html>` tente apenas `ng-app="app"`

Comment: Jovem, você carregou o script com o controller (do Angular) em algum lugar?

Comment: Fiz uma edição e postei o código da Index. Estava faltando.

Comment: Jovem, você precisa **carregar** o controller em algum lugar (geralmente é no index, mas tá tudo tão confuso que nem sei onde deve ser). Chamar ele com a tag `<script>`, entende? Isso é essencial.

Comment: @jbueno, estou carregando ela bem aqui: `<tr data-ng-repeat="lista in listaTipoContatoOperadora">
                                <td>{{ lista.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.nome }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.tipoContato }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.dataUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                                <td>{{ lista.loginUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                            </tr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude o seu controller para:

```
app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:7215/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
    });
};
```

e veja se funciona.

Comment: @NilsonUehara, com o seu exemplo eu consegui remover todos os erros. A lista veio vazia, mas isso é outro post, caso eu não consiga resolver.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem uma referência circular aí.

```
app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController]);
```

Na definição de `TipoContatoOperadoraController` você está passando, como referência, `TipoContatoOperadoraController` - que ainda não existe.

Sua definição também tem um outro problema - a função `tipoContatoOperadora` não é chamada em lugar algum.

Sugestão:

```
app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:7215/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora').success(function (data) {

        $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;

    }).error(function () {

        $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';

    });
}
```

);